# How do I test in both Safari 3 and Safari 4?

Tags: testing, safari

I only have one computer (running OS X), and need to test in both Safari 3 and Safari 4. While Safari 4 is the "official" release, I don't believe it has been pushed in Software Update yet, and therefore probably hasn't been adopted by most users. Even if it has been pushed, it's still a safe bet that many users haven't updated.

The problem is that updating to Safari 4 replaces the system Webkit frameworks, making it difficult to run it at the same time as an older version.

One solution that occurred to me was to download a Webkit build from a few weeks before the release of Safari 3.2.1 and assume it's relatively the same as the release, but I'd rather have the "real thing" to be safe.

Anyone have any good solutions to this outside of having multiple computers/operating systems running?

Comment: As I understand it, Safari 4 comes as part of the 10.5.7 upgrade. So, if users do keep up to date, they will be using Safari 4.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure whether downloading a WebKit build would work. When I installed Safari 4 Public Beta 1, I noticed that the interface on my WebKit builds changed to be like Safari 4 PB1's interface. This would suggest that WebKit builds are affected by the system's WebKit frameworks—how far this goes I'm not sure (the WebKit build has to be different at some point, otherwise it would be useless).

Comment: I'd prefer to just support Safari 4, but I suspect many people put off upgrades (I'm always horrified whenever I help friends with their computers and find dozens of pending updates). Besides, Safari 3 is a very capable browser, so it's not likely that I'm going to have to spend too much time with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A great tool is Multi-Safari:
http://michelf.com/projects/multi-safari/

It does just what you want. It scores a 55 on the acid3, just incase your still paranoid.

You can download multiple versions of Safari 2/3 that contain the correct WebKit version. There is no installation, you just can drag it to your Applications folder, a lot like the nightly WebKit Builds.

Comment: Perfect – this seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. I'm really surprised Apple doesn't provide something like this to developers themselves, thought it could be a calculated move to have developers focus on new Safari features instead of preserving backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=9593851#9593851

There doesn't seem to be an 'official' way to do this and many users report that it is difficult, if not impossible.

That forum post should help, if not solve your problem, but YMMV.